# explicit constructor in std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

According to cplusplus.com, this is the implementation of the std::runtime_error class:

```
class runtime_error : public exception {
public:
  explicit runtime_error (const string& what_arg);
};
```

Since the constructor is explicit, I expected it to only accept std::string objects.

```
throw std::runtime_error("error message");
```

This code compiles (GCC), though. Shouldn't the compiler complain about the implicit const char* to const string conversion?

Comment: That's not how `explicit` works. It prevents a `std::string` from being converted to a `std::runtime_error` implicitly, not a `const char *` to a `std::string`. That one's up to `std::string`'s constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not what explicit means here. Maybe it is easiest to illustrate it with an example:

```
struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(const std::string& s) {}
};

void bar(const Foo&) {}

int main()
{
  Foo f("hello");                // OK: explicit construction from std::string
  Foo f2 = std::string("hello"); // ERROR
  std::string s;
  bar(s);                        // ERROR
}
```

Here, the `explicit` converting constructor means you cannot implicitly construct a `Foo` from an `std::string`. But you can still construct an `std::string` from a `const char*`.

Comment: Note that `bar("hello")` is error, **not** because `Foo()` is explicit. It is rather because it needs two (chained) conversions which is not allowed `(string-literal -> std::string -> Foo)`.

Comment: @Nawaz Good catch! I will remove that one to avoid confusing the issue.